# How do I validate value of a reverse transform input field in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

Scenario:

- Two text input fields `FieldA` and `FieldB`
- Value is stored in a single variable `Var`
- Value of `FieldA` can be derived from the value of `FieldB` and vice versa (think C vs F)
- There is a Value Transformer defined that converts from `A` to `B` and also reverse converse from `B` to `A`.
- `FieldA` is bound to `Var` via Object Controller (model key path is pointing to `Var`)
- `FieldB` is also bound to `Var` (mop is set to `Var`), but also has Value Transformer defined.

So this works fine. If I type in something in `FieldA`, `FieldB` gets updated and if I type something in `FieldB`, `FieldA` gets updated accordingly.

Now I want to do some field validation work. So I:

- Define `validateVar`
- Tick *validates immediately* in the IB on `FieldA`

So far so good. If I type in rubbish in `FieldA`, `validateVar` returns `NO` and I get a nice error message.

$1M question is, how do I validate the `FieldB` after it has changed?

I cannot (really) rely on the fact that `B` converts to `A` and if `A` is invalid I get a message.

My thinking is to do the validation in the reverse value transform function and return something that falls out of the `validateVar` range, but I think this isn't very nice.

Is there a way to do something like `validateFieldB`?

PS. `validateVar` gets called with reverse transformed value from `FieldB`, so effectively the `FieldB` is transformed to `FieldA` value and then `FieldA` calls the validation function.

PPS. OS X Lion. XCode 4.1.