# How do I supply a validated Cocoa input for NSTimeInterval type values?

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoa

I am in need of a Cocoa control, either Objective C or Swift (not SwiftUI, I still support as low as 10.13.x), that accepts text in the format of:

minutes:seconds.fraction

And returns it in either milliseconds, or NSTimeInterval. The former is preferred, the latter is acceptable, I can convert it to milliseconds if necessary.

I need the control to be able to validate the inverse transformation of the value, and only store the value in my NSUserDefaults storage if the value is non-zero, and a valid timestamp.

I see a question here about validating inputs, unanswered: [How do I validate value of a reverse transform input field in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253583/how-do-i-validate-value-of-a-reverse-transform-input-field-in-cocoa)

Can a string simply be fed to an NSTimeInterval for processing? And what about converting NSTimeInterval to a string again? Validation is important, as I don't want the user inputting invalid values and just having them clobber their settings.

Comment: Take a look at `NSFormatter` and its supplied subclasses. `NSDateComponentsFormatter` in particular might be configurable for your use case. More generally, `NSFormatter` is explicitly designed to be subclassed to create custom formatters, including support for two-way conversions and validation. `NSTextField` has a `formatter` property (part of its superclass, `NSControl`) you can use to attach a formatter to it. You can also configure this in Interface Builder. (Note that it's `Formatter`, etc. in Swift where `NS` is stripped off Foundation type names.)

Comment: @AndrewMadsen As far as I know `NSDateComponentsFormatter` doesn't convert from `NSString` to `NSDateComponentsFormatter` or `NSTimeInterval`.

Comment: @kode54 Do you want to use Cocoa Bindings like in the linked question?

Comment: I ended up using this transformer: https://github.com/losnoco/Cog/blob/main/Preferences/Preferences/TimeIntervalToStringTransformer.m But it doesn't validate the input, and doesn't reset the dialog if invalid input is supplied, it merely overwrites the setting with 0. I also had to supply my own addon to support millisecond fractions on the double to string conversion. I would appreciate some knowledge of how to craft a specific two-way ValueTransformer like this in Swift, if that's possible.

Comment: A formatter also transforms values and can validate the input. Use a formatter instead of a value trandformer.

Comment: Alternatively, validate and transform the value in the action method.